# How to remove picture from flutter quill document programmatically onTap method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, quill

I have used flutter quill rich text editor in one of my project where user can create diary from flutter quill toolbar options and also can upload pictures also. So,

Q1) when user upload picture I immediately upload that picture to firesbase storage in _onImagePickCallback() method but if user hit backspace then that picture will be removed from document but it still there in firebase storage. So, how to tackle that backspace or any remove method listener inside flutter quill. (One Approach I tried is don't upload picture immediately but only at the end when user create document and want to create diary, but here I faced problem how to change all those local images to online through uploading to firebase storage.)

Q2) I have used _customEmbedBuilder() method, to draw custom design container for images in flutter quill but I also put a Cross icon on the top of picture so when user tap on that, that picture will be removed from the document regardless where the cursor is, and I don't know how to do this.
Here is the picture and cross icon I did
[image]

This is create diary screen code where I am doing all this.

```
class CreateDiaryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const CreateDiaryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<CreateDiaryScreen> createState() => _CreateDiaryScreenState();
}

class _CreateDiaryScreenState extends State<CreateDiaryScreen> {
bool isDaySelected = false;
QuillController quillController = QuillController.basic();
String imageUrl = '';
int imagesCount = 0;
final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();

DateTime? _selectedDay;

late CalendarFormatChangedCubit calendarFormatChangedCubit;

Future<String> _onImagePickCallback(File file) async {
 String url =
    await context.read<UploadImageCubit>().uploadDiaryImageToFirebase(file);
//print('image callback url :$url');
//
// final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
// final copiedFile =
//     await file.copy('${appDocDir.path}/${Path.basename(file.path)}');
// return copiedFile.path.toString();
 return url;
}

createDiary() {
 Document document = quillController.document;
 var json = jsonEncode(quillController.document.toDelta().toJson());
 print(
     'Plain text: ${quillController.document.toPlainText().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[￼ \n]'), '   
').trim()}');

if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
  ///second check whether user enter some data or not in quill editor.
  if (quillController.document.toPlainText().length > 1) {
    if (isDaySelected) {
      BlocProvider.of<CreateDiaryCubit>(context).uploadDiary(
        diaryTitle: titleController.text,
        diaryText: quillController.document
            .toPlainText()
            .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[￼]'), ' ')

            /// to remove ￼ and \n from string.
            .trim(),
        diaryImage: imageUrl,
        diaryFullDocument: quillController.document,
        diarySelectedDate: _selectedDay ?? DateTime.now(),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Please select date'),
        ),
      );
    }
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Please enter description'),
      ),
    );
   }
  }
}

Widget _customEmbedBuilder(BuildContext context, Embed embed, bool boooll) {
 switch (embed.value.type) {
  case BlockEmbed.imageType:
    return _buildImage(context, embed);
  case BlockEmbed.horizontalRuleType:
    return const Divider();
  default:
    throw UnimplementedError(
        'Embed "${embed.value.type}" is not supported.');
  }
 }

Widget _buildImage(BuildContext context, Embed embed) {
  final imageUrl = embed.value.data;
  return Container(
  height: 160.sp,
  width: 1.sw,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.sp),
  ),
  child: imageUrl.startsWith('http')
      ? ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.sp),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50.sp,
                width: 50.sp,
                child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        )
      : imageUrl.toString().isEmpty
          ? const SizedBox()
          : isBase64(imageUrl)
              ? ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.sp),
                  child: Image.memory(
                    base64.decode(imageUrl),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                )
              : Stack(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 1.sw,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.sp),
                        child: Image.file(
                          File(imageUrl),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      right: 10.sp,
                      top: 5.sp,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 21.58.sp,
                        height: 21.58.sp,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('tapped');
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                size: 16.sp,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
   );
  }

@override
  void initState() {
  print('init called');
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  calendarFormatChangedCubit =
     BlocProvider.of<CalendarFormatChangedCubit>(context);
  _focusNode.addListener(() {
  if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
    ///when focus then change calendar format to week
    calendarFormatChangedCubit.onCalendarFormatChanged(CalendarFormat.week);
   }
 });
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
 calendarFormatChangedCubit.resetCalendarStates();
 }

 showDiaryPostDiscardDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Discard Diary?'),
      content: const Text('If you go back, you will lose your diary post.'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'Yes',
              style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }),
        TextButton(
            child: const Text('No',
                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryColor)),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
       ]),
  );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    if (quillController.document.toPlainText().length > 1 ||
        _formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      /// if condition passed, mean that user typed something into textfield and also written 
 some description
      /// and show alert dialog of diary discard alert.
      showDiaryPostDiscardDialog(context);
      return false;
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      return true;
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFCFEFF),
    appBar: CustomAppBar(
        appBarTitle: 'Add diary',
        diaryAppBar: true,
        onTickPressed: createDiary),
    body: MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<CreateDiaryCubit, CreateDiaryState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is DiarySubmitionSuccess) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Diary created successfully'),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                ),
              );
              Navigator.pop(context);
              titleController.clear();
              quillController.clear();
            }
            if (state is DiarySubmitionNoInternetError) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content:
                      Text('No internet, please connect your internet'),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (state is DiarySubmitionFailed) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Could not create diary, please try again'),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (state is DiarySubmitionError) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('An error occured while uploading diary'),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<CalendarDaySelectedCubit, CalendarDaySelectedState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is CalendarDaySelected) {
              isDaySelected = state.isDaySelected;
              _focusedDay = state.focusDay;
              _selectedDay = state.selectedDay;
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<UploadImageCubit, UploadImageState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is UploadingImage) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: SizedBox(
                      height: 25.sp, child: SnackBarUploadingWidget()),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<UploadImageCubit, UploadImageState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is UploadedImage) {
              ///this is to check as to only first image url upload to firestore document, so 
  we create counter image check.
              imagesCount++;
              if (imagesCount == 1) {
                imageUrl = state.url;
              }
            }
            if (state is UploadingImageFiled) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Error occur'),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 20,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ///calendar, title and description
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 340.sp,
                    // height: 360 + 15.sp,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16.sp, vertical: 0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0.r),
                      color: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        DiaryCalendarWidget(),

                        ///calendar pin
                        Positioned(
                          top: 12.sp,
                          left: 1.sw / 2 - 80.sp,
                          child: const CalendarPins(),
                        ),

                        ///calendar pin
                        Positioned(
                          top: 12.sp,
                          left: 1.sw / 2 + 40.sp,
                          child: const CalendarPins(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                ///title textField
                Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.sp, vertical: 0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      validator: (titleText) {
                        RegExp titleRegExp = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+//$");
                        if (titleText!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Enter Title.';
                        } else if (titleText.length < 20) {
                          return 'Title should be more than 15 characters';
                        } else {
                          final title = titleText;
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      controller: titleController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      textHeight: 20.sp,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                ///text customization section
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.sp, right: 16.sp),
                    child: BlocBuilder<CreateDiaryCubit, CreateDiaryState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        if (state is DiarySubmitting) {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Scrollbar(
                            controller: _scrollController,
                            isAlwaysShown: true,
                            child: QuillEditor(
                                scrollController: _scrollController,
                                paintCursorAboveText: true,
                                embedBuilder: _customEmbedBuilder,
                                scrollPhysics:
                                    const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                customStyleBuilder: (dynamic) {
                                  return GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                                    color: const Color(0xff969798),
                                  );
                                },
                                controller: quillController,
                                scrollable: true,
                                focusNode: _focusNode,
                                autoFocus: false,
                                readOnly: false,
                                placeholder:
                                    'Your diary description here...',
                                expands: false,
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.sp),
                                customStyles: DefaultStyles(
                                  paragraph: DefaultTextBlockStyle(
                                      GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        height: 1.15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                      ),
                                      const Tuple2(16, 0),
                                      const Tuple2(0, 0),
                                      null),
                                  h1: DefaultTextBlockStyle(
                                      GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 32.sp,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        height: 1.15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                      ),
                                      const Tuple2(16, 0),
                                      const Tuple2(0, 0),
                                      null),
                                  sizeSmall: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                                )),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: 1.sw,
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.sp, vertical: 5.sp),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.08),
                      offset: Offset(0, 3.0),
                      blurRadius: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: QuillToolbar.basic(
                  multiRowsDisplay: false,
                  toolbarIconSize: 24.sp,
                  controller: quillController,
                  onImagePickCallback: _onImagePickCallback,
                  iconTheme: const QuillIconTheme(
                      iconUnselectedFillColor: Colors.white,
                      iconUnselectedColor: AppColors.grey,
                      iconSelectedFillColor: AppColors.primaryColor),
                  showVideoButton: false,
                  mediaPickSettingSelector: _selectMediaPickSetting,
                  showAlignmentButtons: true,
                  showHistory: false,
                  showItalicButton: false,
                  showStrikeThrough: false,
                  showCodeBlock: false,
                  showInlineCode: false,
                  showIndent: false,
                  showUnderLineButton: false,
                  showCameraButton: true,
                  showJustifyAlignment: false,
                  showListNumbers: false,
                  showDividers: false,
                  showClearFormat: false,
                  showHeaderStyle: false,
                  showLeftAlignment: false,
                  showCenterAlignment: false,
                  showRightAlignment: false,
                  showQuote: true,
                  showLink: false,
                  showListCheck: false,
                  showSmallButton: true,
                 ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
   );
 }

 Future<MediaPickSetting?> _selectMediaPickSetting(BuildContext context) =>
  showDialog<MediaPickSetting>(
    context: context,
    builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(
              DiaryIcons.image_gallery,
              color: AppColors.primaryColor,
              size: 18.sp,
            ),
            label: Text(
              'Gallery',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(ctx, MediaPickSetting.Gallery),
          ),
          TextButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.link, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            label: Text(
              '  Link  ',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(ctx, MediaPickSetting.Link),
          )
        ],
      ),
     ),
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still need an answer to this but I found a solution to your Problem.

I went for the Q2 you had and upload all the images once it is saved.
This means we need a way to change the controller values.

They way to do is is to go over the operation that are done so far and find the position of the image you want to change.

I have to Maps one containing all the local Urls and one with the Urls i get from the bucket. The following function deals with the entire problem:

```
void replacesLinkFromController(QuillController controller, String imageName) {
var json = jsonEncode(controller.document.toDelta());
List<dynamic> delta = jsonDecode(json);

// Loop over the delta list and search for insert
for (Map<String, dynamic> line in delta) {
  // Each line represents a Map -> line to insert
  for (var key in line.keys) {
    var value = line[key];

    // Check if the key is insert
    if (key == "insert") {
      // Check if the value is a map
      if (value is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        // If it is a map then check if there is a image -> link pair
        for (var newKey in value.keys) {
          if (newKey == "image") {
            // value == local storage
            // Replaces the value
            // Get the new value from the url map
            String storageUrl = getUrlFromImageName(imageName);
            String localUrl = getLocalUrlFromImageName(imageName);
            if (storageUrl != "") {
              value[newKey] = storageUrl;

              var delta = controller.document.toDelta();
              int position = 0;
              int length = 0;
              for (var operation in delta.toList()) {
                position = position + operation.length!;
                if (operation.key == 'insert') {
                  if (operation.data is Map) {
                    Map compare = operation.data as Map;
                    if (compare.containsKey('image')) {
                      if (compare['image'] == localUrl) {
                        length = operation.length!;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              Embeddable newImageWithUrl = Embeddable('image', storageUrl);
              controller.document
                  .replace(position - 1, length, newImageWithUrl);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you can take the part how I replace the images in the controller.